# shift/reduce conflict

Tags: compiler-construction, yacc, bison

priority:

`%nonassoc low

%nonassoc less_than_or_equal less_than equal_operator

%left op_plus op_minus

%left op_multiply op_devision`

rules:

`expr : expr op_plus expr

    | expr op_minus expr

    |expr op_multiply expr

    |expr op_devision expr

    |'~' expr
    |open_paran expr close_paran
    |int_val
    |float_val
    ;`

`bool_expr : expr less_than_or_equal expr

        | expr less_than expr

        |expr equal_operator expr

        |NOT bool_expr

        |TRUE

        |FALSE ;`

`expression : expr %prec low

            |bool_expr;`

I get shift/reduce conflict after expr , any idea how to solve it ??

Answer (score 1):

Add a priority rule for '~' to fix the issue (for example, if '~' is used for negation I would have it associate from the right):

```
%right '~'
```

Comment: Actually, left/right/nonassoc is irrelevant for unary ops -- all that matters is the priority (where it appears in the list of precedences).  You probably want it last (highest precedence)

Comment: This page might be of help: [link](http://uw714doc.sco.com/en/SDK_tools/_Precedence.html)